# Plot pareto front solutions in java

Tags: java, genetic-algorithm, pareto-chart

I have 3 sets of pareto front solutions gathered from MOEA algorithms

I am wondering if there is a java library that can help to draw 3 pareto in the same plot from  3 sets of data.

I have a 2-objective problem. So I guess I need a 2D Plot.

Can you help me by giving an example.

Answer (score 2):

[MOEA Framework](http://moeaframework.org/) comes with many tools for analyzing the output of an MOEA. It includes a diagnostics tool that can generate 2D plots of multiple Pareto fronts. You can import your data using the built-in tools and then display them using the diagnostics tool quite easily. The following image was captured from the diagnostic tool. I executed NSGA-II and SMPSO to solve the LZ3 test problem with 10 seeds. The Approximation Set (e.g. the known Pareto Front) is shown in the upper right-hand corner.

[image: MOEA Diagnostic Tool]

The diagnostics tool in MOEA Framework builds its plots using [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/). If you are only interested in displaying plots of your data (and not performing any other analysis), you may want to just use JFreeChart. However, I recommend using the Diagnostic Tool since it comes with many other features (e.g. ability to calculate Hypervolume, Generational Distance, Additive Epsilon Indicator)

Finally, you can always resort to using the JavaFX charts. It's a fairly robust (albeit immature) API, and the charts are actually quite beautiful. Below you'll find a screenshot of the XY-Scatter plot I built using JavaFX. The code to generate this plot is available below. Additional examples/tutorials are available at http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/charts/jfxpub-charts.htm

[image: JavaFX Chart]

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

import com.sun.javafx.collections.ObservableListWrapper;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.ScatterChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.Data;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.Series;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ScatterChartSample extends Application {

    final double max = 20;
    final double min = 0;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        stage.setTitle("Scatter Chart Sample");
        final NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis(min, max, (max - min) / 10);
        final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis(min, max, (max - min) / 10);
        final ScatterChart<Number, Number> sc = new ScatterChart<>(xAxis,
                yAxis);
        xAxis.setLabel("f1");
        yAxis.setLabel("f2");
        sc.setTitle("Three Pareto Front");

        Series<Number, Number> series1 = new Series<>();
        series1.setName("Algorithm1");
        series1.setData(generateData());

        Series<Number, Number> series2 = new Series<>();
        series2.setName("Algorithm2");
        series2.setData(generateData());

        Series<Number, Number> series3 = new Series<>();
        series3.setName("Algorithm3");
        series3.setData(generateData());

        sc.getData().addAll(series1, series2, series3);
        Scene scene = new Scene(sc, 500, 400);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @return Generates random data resembling a Pareto front 
     */
    public ObservableList<Data<Number, Number>> generateData() {
        ObservableList<Data<Number, Number>> dataList = new ObservableListWrapper<>(
                new ArrayList<>());
        Random rand = new Random();

        double x = min+rand.nextDouble();
        double y = max-rand.nextDouble();

        while (x < max && y > min) {
            x += rand.nextDouble();
            y -= rand.nextDouble();
            dataList.add(new Data<Number, Number>(x, y));
        }
        return dataList;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm new to MOEA: can you explain how to import your data using the built-in tools and then display them using the diagnostics tool? Is there a reference for learning about / generating / handling .adf file (the format asked for load in the Diagnostic Tool)

Comment: @ale-6 The latest user guide is $15 and available at http://moeaframework.org/documentation.html However, the user guide for v2.5 was free and available at http://moeaframework.sourceforge.net/documentation.html